# java Date.parse() over a year off

Tags: java, datetime, groovy

Why does my date come out over a year off? It takes 05/20/2015 and returns the 5th of August 2016.

```
   String d="05/20/2015";

   Date date=Date.parse('dd/MM/yyyy',d);

   //Comes out Fri Aug 05 00:00:00 EDT 2016
```

Comment: The 20th month? What is that?

Comment: @sparkyShorts it's deprecated only from Java 8 and on.

Comment: @sotirios Delimanolis..ha! oops. typo in the question...

Comment: In the question or in your actual code? If only in the question, please update it.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Seriously!? That is the standard American date format...it means May 20th.

Comment: @BahmanM. Seriously!? That is the standard American sarcasm...it means their format is wrong.

Comment: Ah..alright. I missed the humour there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have changed months with days.

```
should be: String d="20/05/2015";

instead of String d="05/20/2015";
```

Comment: Any insight into why Java takes a 20 value for the month and returns a date 15 months from the day? Wouldn't it make sense to a) have an error b) return 20 months from the day?

Comment: @user2782001 If you were using Java's `SimpleDateFormat` instead of Groovy's `Date.parse` helper (which wraps a `SimpleDateFormat`), you could set the leniency to `false`.